# Fade out / in text when changing in React

Tags: javascript, css, animation, reactjs

I want to create a button that changes its text based on the state of the application. I want the old text to fade out, and then the new text to fade in.

[Here's a pen](http://codepen.io/selbekk/pen/xZNOaq) where I've implemented what I want in pure JS.

How would I achieve the same effect in React - or what would be the best approach?

For reference, here is my JSX:

```
<div className="buttons">
  <div className="half">
    <button className="button" onClick={this.chooseLeft}>{this.state.leftButton}</button>
  </div>
  <div className="half">
    <button className="button" onClick={this.chooseRight}>{this.state.rightButton}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

I tried with `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`, but it didn't work quite as expected. It added the new text, then faded out the old one while fading in the new one.

Comment: the same css should work, just code the style attrib into the template

Comment: It would indeed work, but it seems a bit hacky to include a setTimeout etc in the render method.

Comment: you should define something like `this.setText(str)` for the component and put the `setTimeout` in there instead of in `.render()` you can use props/state to trigger the `render()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a similar use case and ended up using a timer to update a couple state variables.

One state var to track the message text, another to track application of a `fade` class in the components `className`. The `fade` class basically controls opacity of the text block.

For instance:

```
...
// in some handler code
  this.setState({fading: true}); // fade out
  this.timer = setTimeout(_ => {
    this.setState({msg: 'Some new text'}); // swap the text
    this.setState({fading: false}); // fade back in
  }, 500); // animation timing offset

// in render
  render() {
    const {msg, fading} = this.state;

    return (
      <h1 className={`${fading ? 'faded' : ''}`}>
        {msg}
      </h1>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can we use React Lifecycle  ?

Comment: Yea that would likely work as a "hook-in" point to run something along the lines of the above. E.g. `componentWillUpdate` apply fade-out with the timer to restore with fade-in. But I think if you relied on `componentDidUpdate` to apply the fade-in then the effect would be nullified due to everything being executed too "quickly"

Answer (score 4):

Use ReactCSSTransitionGroup, part of [react's animation add-ons](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html). It's designed for your exact use case.

Comment: I tried the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`, but then the old text sticks around while the new one is added. In other words - it didn't give me the effect I wanted.

Comment: Did you add a delay in the CSS animation?

Comment: nope didn't. Basically just tried what the React tutorial said, since they had a fade in example.

Comment: Try this for fading out and then in: https://github.com/marnusw/react-css-transition-replace